Laravel 11 Reverb Chat Setup for API {Problem}
My Issues are

after reverb instalation i did not get any ket or secrets in env (how i get it)
laravel did not create echo.php file automatically
i am currently on local host and is it can also work on shared hosting

is it may be the issue related to my system or my laravel or php (i don't get proper data and files)
i am on laravel 11.3 and my php version is 8.2
Recently i create a new laravel project using composer and run every command like
php artisan install:broadcasting
also install reverb and echo and every thing in laravel documentation

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
